# Set the column width when outputting to HTML using SQLPLUS?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am using the 'SET MARKUP HTML ON' option to output a result table from a query to html using SQLPLUS.

I want to be able to explicitly specify that some columns need to be a specific pixel width.

Is this possibly using the 'SET MARKUP HTML OPTION' ?? I would rather not have to just use the regular spooling option, and create the html table manually.

Edited:

I have tried something like:

```
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON PREFORMAT OFF ENTMAP OFF

SPOOL file.html
column aString heading "New Heading"
column aNumber heading "<p style='width:100px'>800SetColA</p>"

SELECT 'Some long String' aString, 3 aNumber FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Some other String' aString, 9 aNumber FROM dual;
SPOOL OFF
```

Which does not work!! the width style tag needs to be set on the th tag and not the p tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the COLUMN ** HEADING to do this
as such:

```
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET MARKUP HTML ON TABLE "class=detail cellspacing=0" ENTMAP OFF
column colA heading "<p style='width:800px'>800SetColA</p>" format a40

column colB heading "<p style='width:10px'>10SetColB</p>" format a40

spool test.html

select level cola, level-5 colb from dual connect by level <10 ;

spool off
```

you can also use style sheets via this approach, tht

Some helpful links:
http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b12170/ch8.htm
http://gennick.com/html.html

Comment: My mistake ... the example doesn't actually work ... the width style needs to be set on the th tag and not the p tag.  Setting it on the p tag doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use stylesheets .. Here is an example :-

```
set markup html on spool on entmap off -
     head '-
     <style type="text/css"> -
        table { font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size:11px;color:#333333;border-width: 1px;border-color: #666666;border-collapse: collapse; } -
        th { border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #dedede; } -
        td { border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff; } -
     </style>' 

spool op.html
exit
```